# Insert all elements from one matrix into another

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have two matrices $A$ and $B$ which are the same size. Each element of $A$ is a list of numbers. Each element of $B$ is just a number. How do I insert each element of $B$ into the corresponding list of $A$?

For example say I have:

```
A = {{{1,2},{3,4}},{{5,6},{7,8}},{{9,10},{11,12}}}
```

> $ = \begin{pmatrix} (1,2) & (3,4)\\ (5,6) & (7,8) \\ (9,10) & (11,12) \end{pmatrix}$

and

```
B = {{0,0},{1,1},{2,2}}
```

> $=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\1&1\\2&2 \end{pmatrix}$

How do I form:

```
{{{1,2,0},{3,4,0}},{{5,6,1},{7,8,1}},{{9,10,2},{11,12,2}}}
```

> $ = \begin{pmatrix} (1,2,0) & (3,4,0)\\ (5,6,1) & (7,8,1) \\ (9,10,2) & (11,12,2) \end{pmatrix}$

Thanks very much for any help

Comment: Are the columns of B always identical as shown in this example?

Comment: No, just giving a simple example so I can understand. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
f = Module[{tmp = ConstantArray[0, Dimensions[#1] + {0, 0, 1}]}, 
            tmp[[All, All, ;; -2]] = #1; tmp[[All, All, -1]] = #2; tmp] &;
f[a, b]
(* {{{1, 2, 0}, {3, 4, 0}},
    {{5, 6, 1}, {7, 8, 1}}, 
    {{9, 10, 2}, {11, 12, 2}}}*)
```

All methods posted so far:

```
f1 = MapThread[Append, {#1, #2}, 2] &;
f2 = Join[#1, Transpose[{#2}, {3, 1, 2}], 3] &;
f3 = MapThread[{Sequence @@ #1, #2} &, {#1, #2}, 2] &;
f4 = MapThread[Flatten[{##}] &, {#1, #2}, 2] &;
f5 = MapThread[Insert[#1, #2, -1] &, {#1, #2}, 2] &;
f6 = MapThread[Join[#1, {#2}] &, {#1, #2}, 2] &;
f7 = Partition[MapThread[Append, {Flatten[#1, 1], #2 // Flatten}], 2] &;
f8 = Join[#1, Map[List, #2, {-1}], 3] &;
f9 = Module[{tmp = ConstantArray[0, Dimensions[#1] + {0, 0, 1}]}, 
            tmp[[All, All, ;; -2]] = #1; tmp[[All, All, -1]] = #2; tmp] &;
```

`Timing`s and `ByteCount`s using Mr.W's test setup:

```
A = RandomInteger[99, {700, 400, 200}];
B = RandomInteger[99, {700, 400}];
Grid[Prepend[Timing@ByteCount@#[A, B], #] & /@ 
    {f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9}, Dividers -> All]~Style~24 (* thanks: Mr.W *)
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for timings.  Regarding the update, why not `Sequence @@ Timing @ ByteCount @ #[A, B]`?  Shorter and clearer IMO.

Comment: Thank you @Mr.W (you should have seen the first version of `Grid[...]`:))

Comment: Hey look, you picked up the Accept. Since you're open to suggestion how about: `Grid[Prepend[Timing @ ByteCount @ #[A, B], #] & /@ {f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9}, 
  Dividers -> All] ~Style~ 24`

Comment: Thank you againm @Mr.W.  Accept is likely to be a mistake -- soon to be corrected now that timings table, with larger fonts, is more readable:) Thomas, thank you .. but are you sure?:)

Comment: Well it contains the most information for future readers.

Answer (score 10):

```
MapThread[Append, {A, B}, 2] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: +1... what sort of code is your email addr expressed in?

Comment: @alancalvitti [brainf*ck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) :D. [Interpreter](http://copy.sh/brainfuck/) / [generator](http://copy.sh/brainfuck/text.html).

Comment: That's the ticket. Thank you user mfvonh.

Answer (score 9):

just a nonpractical variation:

```
Join[A, Map[List, B, {-1}], 3]
```

Comment: +1 for using `Join`.  Actually, this too will preserve packed arrays as above the `"MapCompileLength"` it will compile.  Would you prefer that I delete my answer and include the examples in yours instead?  (Though `Transpose` is still faster I believe.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Please do not delete your answer :) Let both of them stay, if not then yours is more valuable :)

Answer (score 6):

Here are some more ways to do what is asked

```
a = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}, {{9, 10}, {11, 12}}};
b = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}};

MapThread[{Sequence @@ #1, #2} &, {a, b}, 2]

MapThread[Flatten[{##}] &, {a, b}, 2]

MapThread[Insert[#1, #2, -1] &, {a, b}, 2]

MapThread[Join[#1, {#2}] &, {a, b}, 2]
```

and finally, using argument destructuring,

```
Block[{f},
 f[{x_, y_}, z_] := {x, y, z};
 MapThread[f, {a, b}, 2]]
```

All of the above return

> ```
> {{{1, 2, 0}, {3, 4, 0}}, {{5, 6, 1}, {7, 8, 1}}, {{9, 10, 2}, {11, 12, 2}}}
> ```

The common thread (pun intended) running through all these examples is that any function accepting a 1st arg matching `{x_, y_}` and a 2nd arg matching `z_` and producing `{x, y, z}` can be `MapThread-ed` at level 2 to produce the required result.

Answer (score 6):

Unlike other answers here the combination of [`Join`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Join.html) and [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Transpose.html) will preserve a fully packed array:

```
<< Developer`

A = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}, {{9, 10}, {11, 12}}} // ToPackedArray;
B = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}} // ToPackedArray;

Join[A, Transpose[{B}, {3, 1, 2}], 3] // PackedArrayQ
```

> ```
> True
> ```

This allows superior speed and memory management:

```
A = RandomInteger[99, {700, 400, 200}];
B = RandomInteger[99, {700, 400}];

MapThread[Append, {A, B}, 2]          // ByteCount // Timing
Join[A, Transpose[{B}, {3, 1, 2}], 3] // ByteCount // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.436, 262108032}
>
> {0.0393, 225120132}
> ```

---

Edit: Kuba's method will also preserve a packed array when given input large enough to invoke compilation according to the value defined in `SystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "MapCompileLength"]`.

Answer (score 5):

One solution could be like this:

```
Partition[MapThread[Append, {Flatten[A, 1], B // Flatten}], 2]
```