# Riffle but not quite

Tags: list-manipulation

Given the two lists below, is there an in-built command or otherwise neat way of accomplishing the desired output.

```
list = {{1, 2}, {5, 2}, {9, 3}, {6, 5}};
x = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7};
desiredOutput = {{1, 2, x1}, {5, 2, x2}, {9, 3, x3}, {6, 5, x4}};
```

My attempt seems ugly:

```
{list[[#]][[1]], list[[#]][[2]], x[[#]]} & /@ (list // Length // Range)
```

Comment: closely related: [**51407**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51407/5478)

Comment: Also related: [(189)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/189/121), [(13748)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13748/121), [(14494)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14494/121)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Example**

**Code**

```
list = {{1, 2}, {5, 2}, {9, 3}, {6, 5}};
x = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7};

MapThread[Append, {list, x[[;; Length  @ list]]}]
```

**Output**

> {{1, 2, x1}, {5, 2, x2}, {9, 3, x3}, {6, 5, x4}}

**Reference**

[Append](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Append.html)
[MapThread](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html)

Comment: Why does     `MapThread[Append, {list, x[[;; Length  @ list]]}]` work but not `MapThread[Append, {list, x[[;; list // Length]]}]` work? Even though `list // Length` and `Length@list` give the same result?

Comment: @Tom consider `;; list // Length` and `;; (list // Length)`.

Comment: Oh ok, I suppose it's my lack of understanding of the order in which Mathematica computes things  which tripped me up.

Answer (score 16):

There are so many ways to handle a problem like this and which one is preferred with depend on style, performance, the type and shape of your data, ease of recollection, etc., but here are several more:

```
Join[list, x ~Take~ Length[list] ~Partition~ 1, 2]

Riffle[Flatten @ list, x, {3, -1, 3}] ~Partition~ 3

PadRight[list, {Automatic, 3}, List /@ x]
```

And one inspired by J.M.'s use of `Flatten`

```
{list, x} ~Flatten~ {2} // Cases[{{x__}, y_} :> {x, y}]
```

Comment: Yes, that is making nice use of `Riffle` right there. Good when one can read the documentation. :)

Comment: @gwr Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

Shortest so far:

```
i = 1; list /. {a_, b_} :> {a, b, x[[i++]]}
```

Comment: +1, but after you add a `Module` to correctly localize `i` it will be longer than `PadRight`. :^)

Answer (score 10):

```
Transpose[Join[Transpose[list], {Take[x, Length[list]]}]]
```

should be quite fast for long lists. On my work desktop,

```
rand = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {10^5, 2}];
xar = Array[x, 10^6];
AT = AbsoluteTiming;

AT[l1 = Transpose[Join[Transpose[rand], {Take[xar, Length[rand]]}]];]
(* {0.032721, Null} *)

AT[l2 = MapThread[Append, {rand, xar[[;; Length@rand]]}];]
(* {0.112556, Null} *)

AT[l3 = Table[{rand[[k, 1]], rand[[k, 2]], xar[[k]]}, {k, 1, 
     Length[rand]}];]
(* {1.975830, Null} *)

l1 == l2 == l3
(* True *)
```

**EDIT: Some more timings just for fun, in no particular order :)**

```
AT[l4 = (i = 1; rand /. {a_, b_} :> {a, b, xar[[i++]]});]
(* {0.161642, Null} *)

AT[l5 = ArrayFlatten[{{rand, {#} & /@ xar[[1 ;; Length[rand]]]}}];]
(* {0.186327, Null} *)

AT[l6 = Append @@@ 
    DeleteCases[Flatten[{rand, xar}, {{2}, {1}}], {_}];]
(* {1.054091, Null} *)

AT[l7 = MapIndexed[Join[#1, xar[[#2]]] &, rand];]
(* {0.277814, Null} *)

AT[l8 = Join[rand, xar~Take~Length[rand]~Partition~1, 2];]
(* {0.083558, Null} *)

AT[l9 = Riffle[Flatten@rand, xar, {3, -1, 3}]~Partition~3;]
(* {0.028951, Null} *)

AT[l10 = PadRight[rand, {Automatic, 3}, List /@ xar];]
(* {0.315211, Null} *)
```

Answer (score 8):

How about this using Table?

```
Table[{list[[k, 1]], list[[k, 2]], x[[k]]}, {k, 1, Length[list]}]
```

Answer (score 7):

Using MapIndexed...

```
MapIndexed[Join[#1, x[[#2]]] &, list]
```

Answer (score 6):

Yet another possibility, using `Flatten[]` as a "generalized `Transpose[]`":

```
Append @@@ DeleteCases[Flatten[{list, x}, {{2}, {1}}], {_}]
   {{1, 2, x1}, {5, 2, x2}, {9, 3, x3}, {6, 5, x4}}
```

Comment: Shorter: `Append @@@ Cases[Flatten[{list, x}, {2}], {_, _}]`  (and +1)

Comment: Yes, that's more compact, @Mr. Wizard. Nevertheless, I still feel the need to remind myself of what `Flatten[]` is doing by specifying all levels explicitly in the second argument. But that's just my crutch...

Comment: A perfectly valid crutch, IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {{1, 2}, {5, 2}, {9, 3}, {6, 5}}; 
x = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7};
ArrayFlatten[{{list, {#} & /@ x[[1 ;; 4]]}}]

{{1, 2, x1}, {5, 2, x2}, {9, 3, x3}, {6, 5, x4}}
```

Answer (score 3):

I haven't seen this yet, but it may be degenerate with someone else's answer.

```
Append @@@ Partition[Riffle[list, x], 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

`ArrayFlatten[{{list, Transpose[{x[[;; Length@list]]}]}}]`

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4270825) for some interesting comparisons by [Timo](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/138/timo)

Answer (score 3):

I think the preferred way to append columns `X` to matrix `A` is probably:

```
Join[X, A, 2]
```

Adding a single column is slightly less tidy

```
Join[list, Transpose[{x}], 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a = {{1, 2}, {5, 2}, {9, 3}, {6, 5}};
b = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7};
```

Some more possibilities:

`ReplacePart`

```
ReplacePart[i_ :> Append[a[[i]], b[[i]]]] @ a
```

{{1, 2, x1}, {5, 2, x2}, {9, 3, x3}, {6, 5, x4}}

`Table` with `Splice` (new in 12.1)

```
Table[{Splice @ a[[i]], b[[i]]}, {i, Length @ a}]
```

{{1, 2, x1}, {5, 2, x2}, {9, 3, x3}, {6, 5, x4}}

`Transpose` with `TrimRight`

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

Flatten /@ Transpose @ TrimRight[{a, b}]
```

{{1, 2, x1}, {5, 2, x2}, {9, 3, x3}, {6, 5, x4}}

Answer (score 3):

Using `Transpose` and `ReplaceAll` as follows:

```
Transpose@{a, b[[;; Length@a]]} /. x_ /; VectorQ[x] :> Splice@x

(*{{1, 2, x1}, {5, 2, x2}, {9, 3, x3}, {6, 5, x4}}*)
```

Or using `Cases`:

```
Cases[Transpose@{#, b[[;; Length@#]]}, {x : {__}, y_} :> {Splice@x, y}] &@a

(*{{1, 2, x1}, {5, 2, x2}, {9, 3, x3}, {6, 5, x4}}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
list = {{1, 2}, {5, 2}, {9, 3}, {6, 5}};
x = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7};
```

To accomodate varying lengths of each of the above vectors:

```
minlen = Min[Length /@ {list, x}];
listm = list[[1 ;; minlen]];
xm = x[[1 ;; minlen]];
```

Here are some variations without repeating the `Part` construct:

```
SequenceReplace[
 Riffle[listm, xm], {a_List, b_ } :> {Sequence @@ a, b}]

MapThread[Riffle[#1, #2, 1 + Length@#1] &, {listm, xm}]

Join[listm, Transpose[{xm}], 2]

MapThread[Join[#1, {#2}] &, {listm, xm}]

MapThread[Append[#1, #2] &, {listm, xm}]

MapThread[Catenate[{#1, #2}] &, {listm, Transpose[{xm}]}]
```

---

*Result:*

> {{1, 2, x1}, {5, 2, x2}, {9, 3, x3}, {6, 5, x4}}

Answer (score 3):

```
BlockMap[Flatten,Riffle[list, x[[;;Length@list]]],2]

(* {{1,2,x1},{5,2,x2},{9,3,x3},{6,5,x4}} *)
```

In addition, a variation on the neat [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118967/106) given by [xzczd](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1871/xzczd)

```
MapThread[Replace,{list,{a_, b_} :> {a, b, x[[#]]}&/@Range@Length@list}]

(*{{1,2,x1},{5,2,x2},{9,3,x3},{6,5,x4}} *)
```

Comment: (+1) I like to see `BlockMap` in action.