# Riffle two matrices COLUMNWISE; where boh matices have the same number of rows

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I need to "riffle" two matrices; COLUMNWISE.

Say that we have:

```
M1 = {{1, 7, 13, 19, 25, 31}, {2, 8, 14, 20, 26, 32}, {3, 9, 15, 21, 27, 33},
      {4, 10, 16, 22, 28, 34}, {5, 11, 17, 23, 29, 35}, {6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36}};
```

and:

```
M2 = {{A, G, M}, {B, H, N}, {C, I, O}, {D, J, P}, {E, K, Q}, {F, L, R}};
```

I need to get a third matrix:

```
1, A, 7,  G, 13, M, 19, 25, 31
2, B, 8,  H, 14, N, 20, 26, 32
3, C, 9,  I, 15, O, 21, 27, 33
4, D, 10, J, 16, P, 22, 28, 34
5, E, 11, K, 17, Q, 23, 29, 35
6, F, 12, L, 18, R, 24, 30, 36
```

In general; the two matrices `M1` and `M2` have the same number of rows.
On the other hand; the second matrix `M2` may have fewer columns than the first matrix `M1`; (or both matrices could have the same number of columns).

How can I riffle them to get the above third matrix?

Thank you.

Comment: Related: [(51407)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51407/121),
[(118960)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118960/121)

Answer (score 12):

Another option:

```
MapThread[Join @@ Flatten[{##}, {2}] &, {M1, M2}]
```

And a better option:

```
Flatten[{M1, M2}, {3, 1}]\[Transpose]
```

Finally a single-command from [WReach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/142/wreach) in the comments:

```
Flatten[{M1, M2}, {{2}, {3, 1}}]
```

Recommended reading:

- [Flatten command: matrix as second argument](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119/121)

Comment: Hi Mr.Wizard, +1 If you delete the last R at the end of M2 your first command still works but the second one does not.

Comment: Just an oddity but the first solution can handle M2 with different length rows.

Comment: +1.  Another alternative: `Flatten[{M1, M2}, {{2}, {3, 1}}]`.  This will also handle the case proposed by @bobbym.

Comment: @WReach Nice!  I tried to do that all within `Flatten` and failed.  I am not sure what I tried now, but whatever it did not work.

Answer (score 7):

```
M1 = {{1, 7, 13, 19, 25, 31}, {2, 8, 14, 20, 26, 32}, {3, 9, 15, 21, 
    27, 33}, {4, 10, 16, 22, 28, 34}, {5, 11, 17, 23, 29, 35}, {6, 12,
     18, 24, 30, 36}};
M2 = {{a, g, m}, {b, h, n}, {c, i, o}, {d, j, p}, {e, k, g}, {f, l, r}};


Riffle[##, 2 {1, Length@#2, 1}] & @@@ Transpose[{M1, M2}]
```

> {{1, a, 7, g, 13, m, 19, 25, 31},
>       {2, b, 8, h, 14, n, 20, 26, 32},
>       {3, c, 9, i, 15, o, 21, 27, 33},
>       {4, d, 10, j, 16, p, 22, 28, 34},
>       {5, e, 11, k, 17, g, 23, 29, 35},
>       {6, f, 12, l, 18, r, 24, 30, 36}}

Comment: Nice use of `Riffle`.  A distinct advantage of this method over `Flatten` is that the sublists remain packed when possible, e.g. two Integer arrays.

Answer (score 5):

One way:

```
MapThread[
  Join[Riffle[#1[[;; Length@#2]], #2], #1[[1 + Length@#2 ;;]]] &,
  {M1, M2}
 ]
```

Or, similarly,

```
Block[{PlaceHolder},
  MapThread[
    Riffle[#1, PadRight[#2, Length@#1, PlaceHolder]] &,
    {M1, M2}
   ] /. PlaceHolder -> (## &[])
 ]
```

Or, if the rows all have the same length *within* each list, this also works:

```
Transpose@Join[
  Riffle[#1[[;; Length@#2]], #2], #1[[1 + Length@#2 ;;]]
 ] & @@ {Transpose@M1, Transpose@M2}
```

Comment: @GilmarRodriguezPierluissi. Note that it is a bad idea to use capitalized symbols for user-defined functions and variables. Note that `C, D, E, I, K, N, O` are all reserved symbols in *Mathematica*, which is why they are colored differently, and that can lead to problems.

Comment: Thank you all for all your excellent replies!  You ought to try "riffling" in Excel with large number of columns involved.  You are saving me (and others, I'm sure) a lot of perspiration with your inspiration! I'm very grateful!

Comment: Talking about large matrices; when I attempted your riffle command scenarios on two large matrices; I get all sorts of errors.  Please, try: Matrix1 = 
  Table[NumberForm[N[(10 i + 9 j)/70, 3], {4, 2}], {i, 33}, {j, 18}];     Matrix2 = 
  Table[NumberForm[N[(12 i + 17 j)/70, 3], {4, 2}], {i, 33}, {j, 13}];

Comment: @GilmarRodriguezPierluissi. I tried your examples, and they worked fine for me. Did you perhaps reverse the order of the matrices? That matters a lot.

Comment: Oh, gee wheeze!  I was using the labels Matrix 1 and Matrix 2 instead of M1 and M2.  Lord have mercy! Must be Friday!... :-) Thank you!