# Is it possible to insert/add an array (row or columns) in a matrix?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, insert

Assume we have an m by n a non-square matrix. My question is this, is it possible/allowed to insert an arbitrary array ( either row or column) in such matrix so that I can obtain a square matrix? Is there a certain condition to do this or will I violate some rules if I do this?  I will really appreciate your help.

Comment: This can be done, of course. Have a look at `Insert` and `ArrayPad`. Other good matrix constructors that might be helpful are `Join` and `ArrayFlatten`.

Comment: Related: [(51407)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51407/121)

Comment: I'm currently working on my undergraduate thesis about inverse of a non-square matrix, I'm trying to find some pattern to establish this idea by adding/inserting arbitrary rows or columns. In line with this, I'm wondering if it is allowed to do this technique so that I can continue in my study. As I was told, only arrays with natural basis is allowed to be inserted.

Comment: This thread contains a lot of useful examples https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3069/9469

Answer (score 5):

Here an example how to insert a row (would be easier with `Insert`:

```
A = ConstantArray[0, {5, 6}];
row = ConstantArray[1, {1, 6}];
B = Join[A[[1 ;; 2]], row, A[[3 ;;]]];
B // Dimensions
```

> {6,6}

Alternatively, you can use

```
B = Insert[A, row[[1]], 3]
```

Here an example how to insert a row (not that easy with `Insert`):

```
A = ConstantArray[0, {6, 5}];
col = ConstantArray[1, {6, 1}];
B = Join[A[[All, 1 ;; 2]], col, A[[All, 3 ;;]], 2];
B // Dimensions
```

> {6,6}

Comment: The B = Insert[A, row, 3] version requires a 1-dimensional List: row = ConstantArray[1, {6}].

Comment: That makes sense!